# comparing string against $_GET

Tags: php, get

I have 12 different id's I want to compare to `$_GET`. Right now I'm pulling all my id's like this:

```
$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT DISTINCT courseId from training');  
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    while($row = $sth->fetch('courseId')) {
        print_r($row['courseId'] . ',');
    }
```

This returns:

```
8,5,9,10,12,7,4,3,2,6,11,1,
```

Now, I want to check the id's against `$_GET['courseId']`

How do I write an `if` statement to compare the values of `$row['courseId']` and `$_GET['courseId']`. I want to do something like:

```
if($_GET['courseId'] == $row['1']) {
    //Do something here
} elseif ($_GET['courseId'] == $row['2']) {
    //Do something different
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Why not change the query to only get what is in `$_GET`?

Comment: @Jon That might work better, I'll look into it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `print_r` line with:

```
if( $row['courseId'] == $_GET['courseId']) break;
```

Then, after the loop:

```
if( !$row) echo "ERROR: Course ID not found";
else {
    // do stuff with the $row here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I got that working. one more question. When it breaks out of the loop, how can I tell what `courseId` it found? I need to display different material based off of the `courseId`

Comment: Just get `$row['courseId']`, since the current value of `$row` is the one that has the info you want for the `$_GET` variable.